# Creating python script to load api keys from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am currently trying to use a csv file (input.csv) to load multiple api keys so i can download multiple difference documents using the same the api link but the system changes the api key automatically based of input.csv. The input.csv is in the same location as the python script. Also trying to get python to save to a specific location. Any help would be massively appreciated.

I am currently getting the following error when running the script:

```
import csv
import sys
import requests
def query_api(business_id, api_key):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": api_key
    }
    r = requests.get('https://api.link.com', headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
# get filename from command line arguments
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "input.csv"
    sys.exit(1)
csv_filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(csv_filename) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        business_id = row['BusinessId']
        api_key = row['ApiKey']
        query_api(business_id, api_key)
```

I am currently getting the following error when running the script:

```
line 12
    print "input.csv"
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("input.csv")?
```

Comment: print ("input.csv")? what python verion you using?

Comment: Did you actually read the error? It tells you what to fix and what line to change

Comment: Thanks i missed that out